# How to connect to the master node using nodeport Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-networking

I have two pods running on two different VM in the cluster one on the master node and other on the worker node. I have the following docker file exposed port 31700 on the server-side and IP address of server VM node is 192.168.56.105 and for client-side VM IP address is 192.168.56.106.

Dockerfile

```
EXPOSE 31700
```

Server file

```
 sock = socket()
 sock.bind(('0.0.0.0',31700))
```

Client file

```
 sock.connect(('192.168.56.105',31700))
```

Pod : `kubectl get pods`

```
 NAME      STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
 kmaster   Ready    master   25h   v1.19.3
 knode     Ready    worker   25h   v1.19.3
```

Service : `kubectl get services`

```
 NAME            TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
 kubernetes      ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP        25h
 myapp-service   NodePort    10.108.144.147   <none>        80:31700/TCP   49m
```

Detail of the service is described below:

```
kubectl describe services myapp-service

Name:                     myapp-service
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=edge-server
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.108.144.147
Port:                     <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:               80/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  31700/TCP
Endpoints:                192.168.189.5:80
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

When I try to ping through the below command I retrieve Connection refused on both the VMs

```
 curl -v https://192.168.56.105:31700
```

I am able to ping the two pods. Please help me in this on connecting the server and client. Help is highly appreciated. Thank you for your wonderful support.

Comment: seems like you exposed the service at port 80? also, are you sure you want to use https to connect to port 80?

Comment: Hi, @MarkusDresch I did not get your question, would you please clarify this to me. I have exposed  node port with 31700 target port is 80

Comment: but your server listens to 31700, so a target  port of 80 will not work. what's listening on 80?

Comment: Hi @MarkusDresch, it's listening to 31700. Also, I have provided the service nodeport and updated the question. Thank you very much help is highly appreciated.

Comment: but you still forward 31700 to 80. your targetPort must be the port your pod listens on.

Comment: try curl to http instead of https url

Answer (score 0):

You need to use port-forwarding to access applications in your cluster 
(see https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/).

You can forward a *local* port to a *port on the Pod* with:

```
kubectl port-forward service/kubernetes <local-port>:443
```

`myapp-service` is exposing (listening to) 31700, but you should use port 80.

Comment: Thanks for your wonderful suggestion @CasperDijkstra, I tried port forwarding but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

In your Dockerfile , it should be "EXPOSE 80" instead of "EXPOSE 31700" ( Assuming your container listening on port 80)

Comment: Hi @confusedgenius, I tried this but it's not working